# DSL configuration within activerecord model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dsl, rails-activerecord

I want to build reports for some database data. I store report's settings in database through activerecord models, but I don't want that, I want to write something like

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    report do
        name   "Total Sales by Departments"
        method :name

        report_field do
            name     "Total Sales"
            action   :sum
            relation "Sales"
            method   :spent
        end

        report_field do
            name     "Average Sales"
            action   :avg
            relation "Sales"
            method   :spent
        end
    end
end
```

Can someone please tell me how this is possible to do and what should I read, maybe some examples of other things that are similar to my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by reading about [Class Macros](http://techie.lucaspr.im/creating-class-macros/).